# popup hints on product page required field

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, product-page

This is my [product page](http://smartphone-deals.nl/index.php/iphone-5c-119.html)

If customer no select storage or color and click "add to cart" nothing happens so I want make popup with hints but I dont know wherein the file and how it should look condition.

Comment: Hello Artur, welcome to Magento SE. Your question seems to be bit broad. Please be specific on your question. Put codes which you have tried so far.

Comment: I corrected my question

Comment: You do have JS alert working when user's not selecting one of required options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax add to cart [JS](http://smartphone-deals.nl/js/sns/proaddto/script.js) overriding default `productAddToCartForm.submit` function.

You can find this unction end of the JS file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    SnsProaddto.init();
    setInterval("SnsProaddto.init()", 1000);
    window.setLocation = function(args) {
        if (args.indexOf('checkout/cart/add') !== -1) {
            SnsProaddto.locationAddtocart(args);
        } else if (args.indexOf('?options=cart')) {
            SnsProaddto.destroyImgFly();
            window.location = args;
            //SnsProaddto.displayOptions();
        }
    }
    if (typeof productAddToCartForm != 'undefined') {
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function() {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                SnsProaddto.destroyImgFly();
                jQuery('#proaddto_loading').show();
                var dataf = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').serialize();
                dataf += '&isAjax=1';
                url = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').attr('action');
                url = url.replace("checkout/cart", "proaddto/index");
                url = SnsProaddto.cleanUrl(url);
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: dataf,
                    success: function(data) {
                        jQuery('#proaddto_loading').hide();
                        SnsProaddto.setCartResult(data);
                        SnsProaddto.flyImgToCart();
                    }
                });
            }

            else {
                // popup condition
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I add alert but still not heppend

Comment: you have added it in productAddToCartForm.submitLight. you need to add in productAddToCartForm.submit

Comment: I add also in productAddToCartForm.submit

Comment: Ohhh, I see you are using AJAX add to cart which is overriding above js function. Do you know which is the module for your ajax or from where this ajax call is made

Comment: I think it is calling from http://smartphone-deals.nl/js/sns/proaddto/script.js js and you can find productAddToCartForm.submit in last function.

Answer (score 0):

code

```
 productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;
                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                try {
                    this.form.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }
                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            }
            else {
                alert("dddddd");
            }
```